# affinetransform rotate, bufferedimages being cut

Tags: rotation, bufferedimage, cut, affinetransform

I'm making a game and recently ran into a problem which occurs when rotating buffered images using affinetransform. The images are rotated around their own center. And for example when rotated 45 degrees, the corners facing up and left are cut off, all pixels that are positioned lower than the original x or y position of the image is not shown.

This is the code i use for rotating the bufferedimage:

```
setRad();
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.rotate(-rad, width/2, height/2);
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
bImage = op.filter(startImage, null);
```

setRad() gives the angle depending on x- and y speed
startImage is the loaded image
bImage is the one getting returned to the main class.

I figured a way to solve this would be enlarging the image file, adding empty space around it so i dont use the corners getting cut. But this would decrease the performance some and i would rather stick with a proper solution if possible. Hope it's all clear!

//Snorbird

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your source image is not exactly quadratic.
When you implement the AffineTransform rotation with `at.rotate(-rad, width/2, height/2);`, it is the same as:

```java
at.translate(width/2,height/2);
at.rotate(rads);
at.translate(-width/2,-height/2);
```

So, when it execute the last line, it translates to the origin. And if the width is greater than y (or vice versa), than the origin of the transform will be translated to a smaller distance than the side of greater length.

For example, if your width is 30 and your height is  60, than the origin point will be set as (-15,-30) from where the transform was original set. So, when you translate it, say, 90 degrees, the image will end up with "width" 60 and "height" 30, but according to the origin point, the image original bottom will be drawn at (-30,0), so it overflows the AffineTransform in -15 in X axis. Then this part of image will cut.

To correct this, you can use the following code instead:

```java
    double degreesToRotate = 90;
    double locationX =bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2;
    double locationY = bufferedImage.getHeight() / 2;

    double diff = Math.abs(bufferedImage.getWidth() - bufferedImage.getHeight());

    //To correct the set of origin point and the overflow
    double rotationRequired = Math.toRadians(degreesToRotate);
    double unitX = Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRequired));
    double unitY = Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRequired));

    double correctUx = unitX;
    double correctUy = unitY;

    //if the height is greater than the width, so you have to 'change' the axis to correct the overflow
    if(bufferedImage.getWidth() < bufferedImage.getHeight()){
        correctUx = unitY;
        correctUy = unitX;
    }

    int posAffineTransformOpX = posX-(int)(locationX)-(int)(correctUx*diff);
    int posAffineTransformOpY = posY-(int)(locationY)-(int)(correctUy*diff);

    //translate the image center to same diff that dislocates the origin, to correct its point set
    AffineTransform objTrans = new AffineTransform();
    objTrans.translate(correctUx*diff, correctUy*diff);
    objTrans.rotate(rotationRequired, locationX, locationY);

    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(objTrans, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    // Drawing the rotated image at the required drawing locations
    graphic2dObj.drawImage(op.filter(bufferedImage, null), posAffineTransformOpX, posAffineTransformOpY, null);
```

Hope it help.